# Qt5.6 signals and slots overloading

Tags: c++, signals, slots, qt5.6

I have created a class for handling data received from slots and have created several overloaded methods of the same name with a different parameter type.

Is it possible to use overloaded methods as slots?

I have two declarations so far:

```
    void notify(uint uintData);
    void notify(float fltData);
```

However the 2nd produces a warning at runtime:

```
    QObject::connect: No such slot clsSlot::notify(float)
```

Found this which implies it should work: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

But it doesn't...

From the class 'clsSlot':

```
    public slots:
        void notify(uint uintValue);
        void notify(float fltValue);
```

Implementation:

```
    void clsSlot::notify(float fltValue) {
        notifyPrimitive(meID, QString::number(fltValue));
    }
    void clsSlot::notify(uint uintValue) {
        notifyPrimitive(meID, QString::number(uinValue));
    }
```

Connect call:

```
        QObject::connect(Fcs::Mount::GetRef()
                        ,&Fcs::Mount::signalElevation
                        ,pobjHandler, &clsSlot::notify);
```

pobjHandler is an pointer to an instance of clsSlot.

Comment: Yes, you can have overloaded slots. You'll need to show more code. For example, how are you actually performing the connection? How is the slot declared and defined?

Comment: Edited with declaration and connect call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QObject::connect(Fcs::Mount::GetRef()
    ,&Fcs::Mount::signalElevation
    ,pobjHandler, &clsSlot::notify);
```

The problem with your above code is that there is more than one `notify` function (i.e., since it's overloaded). You have to state exactly which one is to be connected. You could do it with a cast but in this case you should just use the older Qt syntax. For example:

```
connect(sender, SIGNAL(signalFn(float)), this, SLOT(notify(float)));
connect(sender, SIGNAL(signalFn(uint)), this, SLOT(notify(uint)));
```

Obviously, the above connect code is just an example of the syntax and you'll need to fill it in with your appropriate code (e.g., replace `sender` with `Fcs::Mount::GetRef()` perhaps).

---

Edit: Here is a [link](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax#Overload) to the Qt documentation explaining why the old syntax must be used for overloads.

> **Overload**
>
> As you might see in the example above, connecting to QAbstractSocket::error is not really beautiful since error has an overload, and taking the address of an overloaded function requires explicit casting, e.g. a connection that previously was made as follows:
>
> ```
> connect(mySpinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), mySlider, SLOT(setValue(int));
> ```
>
> cannot be simply converted to:
>
> ```
> connect(mySpinBox, &QSpinBox::valueChanged, mySlider, &QSlider::setValue);
> ```
>
> ...because QSpinBox has two signals named valueChanged() with different arguments. Instead, the new code needs to be:
>
> ```
> connect(mySpinBox, static_cast<void (QSpinBox::*)(int)>(&QSpinBox::valueChanged), mySlider, &QSlider::setValue);
> ```
>
> Some macro could help (with c11 or typeof extensions)
>   The best thing is probably to recommend not to overload signals or slots …
>
> … but we have been adding overloads in past minor releases of Qt because taking the address of a function was not a use case we support. But now this would be impossible without breaking the source compatibility.

Comment: I was hoping that the compiler would select the correct instance of notify for me, as thats why I overloaded it.

Comment: @SPlatten The correct overload will be called but you must explicitly connect each overload.

Comment: Trying it, but not getting any further, it compiles but signals don't get to slots.

Comment: @SPlatten You must have a problem somewhere else. I added a link to the Qt documentation explaining the new and old syntax. It explicitly talks about overloaded slots.